# Energy Losses - Hot Water Tanks

Tags: thermal-conductivity

In the interest of saving steam and therefore money, can someone clarify if extra energy is required to maintain the temperature of water in an enclosed, vented and insulated tank depending on the level within the tank? Would a Full tank use the same energy as a partially filled tank once both tanks have reached the required temperature. Assume two identical tanks, one full the other half full, both have water @ 48deg.
Temperature is controlled by the on/off injection of steam within 3deg deadband.

My assumption is that to maintain a constant temperature, both tanks would require the same energy input as the external surface temperature would be the same. (assuming convection would heat the air inside to the same temperature as water) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hot water will be a better conductor of heat through the water heater's walls than hot air.  This means that there will be a bit more heat loss from a full water heater than from one that is partially full, but I wouldn't expect the difference to be large.

Comment: Thanks David,With the vessel being insulated I would expect the difference to be minimal. How many % constitutes "large"?

Comment: @Boorune, "large" would have to be in terms of total cost.  If your monthly energy bill is 1000 dollars, a 5% increase results in 50 dollars, but if your monthly energy bill is 10000 dollars, a 5% increase results in 500 dollars.  While both examples are a 5% increase, I seriously doubt that you would say that the 500 dollar loss is equivalent to the 50 dollar loss.  However, strictly on a percentage basis, I would not expect more than a 5% difference.